# How to create a foreignkey Model in django using class based CreateView

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have created a salesmanager app which consist two models Company and Item, such that

```
#sales/models.py


class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=9)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address)
    contact_person = models.ForeignKey(ContactPerson)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Item(TimeStampedModel):
    """Item model """

    name = models.CharField("Item name", max_length=255)
    tag = models.CharField("Item tag", max_length=30, unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag + "-" + self.name
```

What I want is to create a form to update these models from a single page using single button.so to accomplish this, I have created a Class based view, such that

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView


class ItemCreateView(CreateView):
    """Create a item """
    template_name = 'salesmanager/item_create_form.html'
    success_url = '/dashboard'
    model = Item
    #created_at and updated_at fields are from TimeStamped model
    fields = ('name','tag', 'price', 'created_at', 'updated_at')
```

The problem what I want to solve is,  how do I render the Foreign key fields in  the `item_create_from.html` template ?

and another problem is `created_at` and `updated_at` which are inherited from TimeStampedModel (learn from Twoscoops of django) are not recognized in the CreateView class.

can't we create a multiple relation forms using Classbased view. If not should I go with Function based view.

Comment: You shouldn't need to include `created_at` and `updated_at` in your Form or CreateView because those are "auto-fields" and will updated / have there values set automatically.

Comment: Thank you, yes I tried it, by removing the `auto_now_add`, and `auto_now` in this case the form rendered, else it will updated automatically,